# Making percentage on pie chart more readable

Tags: python, pie-chart

I have a pie chart and some of the slices are very small (<1%), and as of now its very hard to read the percentage. The best I've done is exploded these particular slices so they don't overlap with the rest of the chart, but I know it can be better. How can I change the position of both my label and percentage? What I would prefer to do is have a line leading from the slice to a text of the label and its percentage. Here is my code:

```
#Pie chart of different collision types

labels = 'VEH', 'FIXED OBJ', 'OTHER-COLLISION','ANIMAL','NON-COLLISION','PED','BICYCLE'
colors = 'orange', 'green', 'red','pink','yellow','blue','purple'
x = acc_colls
explode = (0,0,0,0,0,2.5,2.5)  # explode slice 2-4 

plt.pie(x, labels=labels, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=210,radius=1.8)
# plt.legend(pie[0],labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5), loc="lower left", fontsize=12, 
#            bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
plt.title("Types of Collisions", y=-0.35)
```

Here's my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ95a.png

Comment: For this particular reason pie charts are generally considered not great for data visualisation, in particular, human sight is not very well adapted to judging areas, which is what pie charts are all about. I'd recommend using other visualisation type.

Comment: Oh, wow I didn't know that at all. Thank you for this. I'll transition to something else. @pavel

Comment: Depending on your data I'd recommend something simple like a bar chart. [Here's](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6?r=US&IR=T) for example an article from Business Insider explaining issues with pie charts in detail.